# Can we upload deobfuscation file on fabric?

Tags: android, obfuscation, google-fabric, deobfuscation

While releasing my android application on play store I have also uploaded the mapping.txt file for the deobfuscation of crash or error stack trace. I want to know is it possible to do same in Fabric?. Can we upload a mapping.txt file for deobfuscation of stack trace on fabric.io?

Comment: It automatically does that if configured according to the guidelines mentioned here https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html

Comment: Right now it is only possible to do this at build time per the instructions Sharj provided :)

Comment: with this automated approach, when is the mapping.txt uploaded? If I generate a signed build it's done as part of that process? What if I make a signed build and don't change the version info, will it overwrite what was previously uploaded ?

Comment: Personally, I would prefer having some manual control over the process

Comment: After the configuration update to proguard rules, on Android Studio 3.2, I now get `Unknown option '-keepresourcexmlelements'`